# Insert a value to a sorted list via list comprehension Python

Tags: python

I have an assignment to add a value to a sorted list using list comprehension.  I'm not allowed to import modules, only list comprehension, preferably a one liner.  I'm not allowed to create functions and use them aswell.
I'm completely in the dark with this problem.  Hopefully someone can help :)

Edit: I don't need to mutate the current list. In fact, I'm trying my solution right now with .pop, I need to create a new list with the element properly added, but I still can't figure out much.

Comment: This seems like very poorly-thought-out assignment. List comprehensions are functional constructs, and shouldn't be used to mutate an existing list. They create *new lists*

Comment: The assign is probably to make a new list with the new value added in the right place.  I doubt if they mean to mutate the original list.  I suspect I need to use one or more `if` clauses in the list comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah that's what they meant, sorry if I wrote it poorly. But I still can't figure it out.  I tried to experiment a bit with popping elements if they're smaller than the value or if they're bigger and the amount of time the value has appeard is bigger than 1, but it doesnt work out too well

Comment: You need to specify precisely what you need. Please use the help center to learn how to write a well-formed question.

Comment: you fundamentally changed the problem statement with that edit ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    sorted_a.insert(next(i for i,lhs,rhs in enumerate(zip(sorted_a,sorted_a[1:])) if lhs <= value <= rhs),value)
except StopIteration: 
    sorted_a.append(value)
```

I guess ....

with your new problem statement

```
 [x for x in sorted_a if x <= value] + [value,] + [y for y in sorted_a if y >= value]
```

you could certainly improve the big-O complexity

Comment: A+ for you mr Joran ;)

Comment: Except after removing that list comprehension because it wasn't necessary you're no longer meeting specs for the OP!

Comment: meh its a generator-comprehension Im sure his teacher will give him extra credit if he can explain it ;P

Comment: Be careful what you ask for, I guess!

Comment: @JoranBeasley I did change it but it doesn't mean adding the value to the original list isn't a good solution, because all in all, what I need to do is insert the value to the list using list comprehension, it doesn't matter how I do it.

Comment: @OmriK If you submit Joran's answer, please let us know how it goes.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I didn't even think of concatenating the values from different sub-lists. Brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For bisecting the list, you may use [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) *(for other readers referencing the answer in future)* as:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect

>>> my_list = [2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 20]
>>> num = 12

>>> index = bisect(my_list, num)
>>> my_list[:index]+[num] + my_list[index:]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20]
```

But since you can not import libraries, you may use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> my_list = [2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 20]
>>> num = 12

>>> sum([[i, num] if i<num<j else [i] for i, j in zip(my_list,my_list[1:])], [])
[2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: I would have used `itertools.chain` to flatten the list, but that's an imported module.  Using `sum(alist,[])` to flatten is a new idiom for me.

Comment: @hpaulj `itertools.chain` is definitely a better way for chaining. As you guessed it right; `sum` is used to prevent imports

Comment: its much slower than itertools.chain ... but it meets the problem definition (even after problem edit...) so thats why my +1 :P